# Find a Location on the map Via latitude and longitude in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have many latitude and longitude data in my database, I want to use these data to find locations on the map in street view in my website that has developed by ASP.NET. I want to find component for ASP.NET that when I extract these data from database, these component have ability to use them and show the locations. So I looking back from you to guide me.
Thanks All+

Comment: Have you heard of Google Maps?

Answer (score 0):

I used Google map API v3.0 for showing location in an Asp .net website.You can use it.But It doesn't have StreetView.

Answer (score 0):

Google Map API v3.0 does have street view.

Check out this documentation on Code.Google.com

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#StreetView

and this is some sample code in javascript to add street view (taken from the documentation itself)

```
var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(42.345573,-71.098326);
  var mapOptions = {
    center: fenway,
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
```

hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the lat,long that you have given, some of the lat,long does have streetview and some dont.